# Как состаить правильно SQL запрос чтобы вернуть JSON

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы первая условно с пользователями вторая с ссылками на их социальные сети
как мне сделать запрос чтобы возвращаемый результат был вида

```
{
 "username": "username",
 "age": "age",
 "social" : {
  "instagram": "instagram"
 }
}
```

При использовании JOIN не создаются подобъекты.

Comment: Почему Вы решили что JSON должна генерировать БД?

Comment: То есть мне нужно сделать два запроса?

Comment: т.е. какое отношение сервер базы данных имеет к формированию JSON ?

Comment: А почему бы серверу БД не генерировать JSON? он, между прочим, умеет...

Comment: *`"social" : { "instagram": "instagram" }`* - а нафига значение делать ещё и именем?

Comment: Это для примера просто

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT( 'username', user.name,
                    'age', user.age,
                    'social', JSON_ARRAYAGG(socnet.name) )
FROM user
JOIN socnet USING (user_id)
GROUP BY user.name, user.age
```